$f:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{C}$ which satisfies $f(e^{-it})=\overline{f(e^{it})}$

Find all the continuous functions $f$ such that $f:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{C}$ which satisfies $f(e^{-it})=\overline{f(e^{it})}$.

I was trying to find some concrete examples of abelian real $C^*$-algebras. Any abelian real $C^*$-algebras are of the form
$$C(X,-)= \{f| f \in C(X,\mathbb{C}) \text{ and } f(\bar{t})=\overline{f(t)}, \text{ where } - \text{ is a homemorphism of } X \text{ with period 2} \}$$
where $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space. The above question occured while finding such examples.
I was looking for all the homeomorphisms of the compact spaces which has period $2$. Is there any characterization of such homeomorphisms for arbitrary compact Hausdorff spaces?
Thanks in advance.

This is quite hopeless. There's an enormous variety of compact (Hausdorff) spaces and homeomorphisms of those spaces. For a large easy class of examples, take any compact group (e.g. any profinite group) $G$ and consider the map $g \mapsto g^{-1}$.

@QiaochuYuan Expecting results for arbitrary topological spaces could be a lot. But I would be happy if I could find some characterization of those homeomorphisms for compact subspaces in complex Euclidean spaces.

For your quoted question about $S^1$, writing out Fourier series shows such $f$ are exactly those whose Fourier coefficients are all real. Put it another way, they are exactly those $f$ s.t. $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{int}f(it) , dt \in \mathbb{R}$ for any integer $n$.
